# My LogIn PHP form doesn't work. I believe that my $hash = $row['password']; is the problem, but am not really sure

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently in the process of creating my first website with PHP. I have created a MySQL database with a database and a table called "users" with the columns in order from left to right, "Personalid" (AUTOINCREMENT), "username" & "password" (hashed using `password_hash($POST_['password'])`.

Here is my HTML code for the form below

```
 <form  method="post" action="idk.php">
                    <h1>Sign In</h1>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"/>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">Sign In</button>
                </form>
```

Here's my php form, called idk.php

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root',"user_hirsa");
if(!$conn){
   die('Could not Connect My Sql:' .mysql_error());
}
else {
    echo "Connected";
}
?>


<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $myusername);

$myusername = $_POST['username'];
$mypassword = $_POST['password'];
$hash = $row['password'];

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($myusername, $mypassword);
$row = $stmt->fetch(); //fetch DB results


if (!empty($row)) { // checks if the user actually exists(true/false returned)
    if (password_verify($mypassword, $hash)) {
        echo 'success'; // password_verify success!
    } else {
    echo 'failed';
    }
} else {
    echo "This user does not exist"; //username entered does not match any in DB
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

I believe that my problem is with the `$hash = $row['password']`, but I don't really know. My outcome is "connected" for the database connection, but always "failed", even if I enter a correct password. When I enter a wrong username it displays "This user does not exist", so no problem there.

Comment: your connection to the database work correctly right?

Comment: Maybe the assignment `$hash = $row['password'];` should come after the assignment `$row = $stmt->fetch();`, not before, when `$row` isn't even set to anything...

Comment: For one thing, you can't mix mysql apis with `mysql_error()`. Plus, that isn't for a connection error, it's to check for errors on a mysql_ query.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Hi! Yes, the connection work well.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @tadman I know there are much easier ways to do this, like using firebase etc., but this is only for my own benefit, so then when PHP files will get harder, it will be easier for me to troubleshoot.

Comment: It's not about using Firebase, it's about using PHP effectively. Frameworks are a huge component in being successful at building applications. If you shun these you're forced to painfully, tediously re-invent twenty plus years of history and learning yourself. It's important to learn fundamentals, but it's also important to understand those in the context of solving problems, not re-inventing things from first-principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct. The hash should come from the database. A better naming convention for your variables maybe would help notice the mistake.

I made few changes to your script:

```
<?php

// enable error reporting
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', "user_hirsa");
// you should set the correct charset here
// $conn->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

```
<?php

$myusername = $_POST['username'];
$mypassword = $_POST['password']; // plain password coming from login form

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $myusername);
$stmt->execute();

// bind columns to variables
$stmt->bind_result($hashInDB);
$row = $stmt->fetch(); //fetch DB results

if ($row) { // checks if the user actually exists(true/false returned)
    if (password_verify($mypassword, $hashInDB)) {
        echo 'success'; // password_verify success!
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
} else {
    echo "This user does not exist"; //username entered does not match any in DB
}

// you don't need these
// $stmt->close();
// $conn->close();
```

Generally it is a bad idea to let others know which user does/doesn't exist in the database. Just say that credentials are incorrect.

Comment: I love you so much, man! I've been troubleshooting this for around 4 hours now and I can't thank you enough. It works perfectly with no problem! You are the real G!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to access $row before it is instantiated. As such, your $hash will be null. Try setting your hash after retrieving the results.

```
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$hash = $row['password'];
```

Comment: DV should explain. `$hash = $row['password'];` before `$row = $stmt->fetch();` will cause an issue at `if (password_verify($mypassword, $hash)) {`.